# Java JButton pass method call to actionlistener

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to pass a method name to the action listener so that way it can call that method without 50 if statements. I know that in C++ there are function pointers, but that is not a thing in java. Is there a way in java to have something along the lines of

```
actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e){
    String command = e.getSource().getActionCommand()
    //use command to look up a method on the implementing class
    //and call it without an if
```

All of the methods that need to be called have no return and have no value that needs to be passed to them, they can get all the information they would need from the frame that owns it. I'm thinking reflection is a valid option but my experience with it is limited in Java and I have never read anything nice about it.

This is for a frame work idea so that way the ActionListener can be striped out of the project and reused with little to no modification. I am working with a frame work someone else developed at my work that does this in C# and a whole lot of what ever this guy was on when he wrote it. So I'm trying to create a Java implementation of it because C# has its limitations (Windows).

Comment: Kind of, would I really recommend it, probably not..  You could take a look at [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) or you could use a `Map` which contained a common `interface` implementation with a required method, which based on your `Action` or `actionCommand`, would be able to look up which instance it should execute, which would be WAY better then resorting to reflection

Comment: @MadProgrammer That sounds much more fun then reflection, but I've never even touched Maps before. So are you saying to use setActionMap on the button or give the ActionListener class a map and use the string from action command as the keys to look up the method?

Comment: Generally you would have a `Map` as a instance field, whose key would map to the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`, so when executed, you look up you command and execute it's method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways you could do it, one might be to devise a common interface, which all your "commands" would need to implement, it would have a single method, which your `ActionListener` could then execute.

For example...

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}
```

You would then have a `Map` in your UI which would map `actionCommand`s to instances of `Command`s

```
public class ... extends ... {
    private Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>(25);
    //...
```

Now, you could have a nice "add" method which would allow you to add commands dynamically, creating a new `JButton` for each new command or simply set it up yourself within the class based on your needs

Then in your `ActionListener`, you'd simply get the `actionCommand` property, look up the `Command` in the `Map` and `execute` it if it's valid

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Command cmd = commands.get(e.getActionCommand());
    if (cmd != null) {
        cmd.execute();
    }
}
```

For example...

```
package javaapplication659;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCommand();
    }

    public TestCommand() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>(25);
        private ActionListener actionListener;
        private GridBagConstraints gbc;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
            actionListener = new ActionHandler();
            add("Take over the world", new Command() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    System.out.println("Take over the world");
                }
            });
            add("Quwell up rising", new Command() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    System.out.println("Bring the boot down");
                }
            });
            add("Buy milk", new Command() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    System.out.println("Buy milk");
                }
            });
        }

        public void add(String text, Command cmd) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(text);
            btn.addActionListener(actionListener);
            commands.put(text, cmd);
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Command cmd = commands.get(e.getActionCommand());
        if (cmd != null) {
            cmd.execute();
        }
    }

        }

    }

    public interface Command {
        public void execute();
    }
}
```

Now, this is pretty basic example and could be much more complex, depending on your needs, but it demonstrates the basic idea

Comment: This is a very nice implementation and looks nicer then reflection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a far from perfect solution, but though I might just say it here...

JButtonSpecial is my class, extends JButton. JButtonSpecial will contain the method you'd want to pass into the ActionListener. Then you can do something like,

```
button=new JButtonSpecial("Click Here");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButtonSpecial tmpButton = (JButtonSpecial)e.getSource();
      tmpButton.yourCustomMethod();//this method will be defined in JButtonSpecial
   }
});
```

I agree you'll want to hardcode the method name in there, but you can change the implementation of the method from object to object...

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to say going off of your code 'button=new JButtonSpecial(){specialMethod(){/*method stuff*/}` I like this idea considering anyone implementing it could do what ever they wanted after this but it seems a little ugly in the implementation and this doesn't account for the menuItems textFields and the many other things that can have an actionListiner

Comment: Not unless you create action listener specific for all those types you'd use... I agree it's bit ugly

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have function pointers so you will have to do something like this:

```
private JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
public YourClass()
{
    ...
    button.setActionCommand("foo");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    ...
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command.equals("foo"))
        foo();
    else if(...)
}
```

Also as a sidenote- `e.getSource().getActionCommand()` will give you a syntax error. `getActionCommand()` is a method in `ActionEvent`, and `getSource()` returns an object so you would do `e.getActionCommand()`